# Dynamically creating session on Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Actually i have created one session object and i am storing multiple textbox, radio & checkbox value in that session.

Here is my Code(My Insertion page, where i'll insert values and store in session).

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Creating DataTable dt
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //Creating DataTable Columns
    dt.Columns.Add("FName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("MName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("LName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("EId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("PCode", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("AOI", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(txtFN.Text, txtMN.Text, txtLN.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEId.Text, ddlState.Text, ddlCity.Text, txtCountry.Text, txtPCode.Text, rdGender.SelectedValue, cbAOI.SelectedValue);

    //Creating Session object to store DataTable dt
    Session.Add("Insert", dt);

    lblMandatory.Text = "Successfully Inserted into Database";
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```

I just wanted to know, is there any way to create new session whenever i click Register button i.e., i don't want to overwrite existing session, but on each button click, i want to create new session automatically.

My Home Page, where i'll display this dataTable using GridView

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{  
    if ((!IsPostBack) && (Session["Insert"] != null)) 
    {
        //At another place you retrieve datatable:
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        dt = (DataTable)Session["Insert"];

        //Binding GridView with DataTable dt
        gdvView.DataSource = dt;
        gdvView.DataBind();
   }
}
```

My Problem is, everytime GridView column get replaced with new GridView column, since my session get replaced with new values.
So is there any way, i can store new session value into gridview without loosing previous values from gridview.

Comment: Your code Session.Add() does not check for existing session. Just use Session["insert"] = dt, then manage the dt to add new rows everytime. Then use the dt to check the count like dt.Rows.Count or ((DataTable)Session["insert"]).Count

Comment: Thanks agentpx, it helped, but still i want to know how to automatically create session object. In above code, at first i am creating session["insert"] on button click. But what i actually want is, if next time i click button, it should create new session with some other id or object. So that finally i can have multiple session generated automatically on each button click.

Comment: Session.Add("Insert" + txtEId.Text.Trim(),dt);

Comment: Please go through me code again, and try to give solution now. Thanks

Comment: Oh its not the session that is your problem. I'm not sure but GridView seems to cache DataSources and properties for performance. What  I did on the same problem was to set GridView = Null, or GridView.Datasource = Null. I can't remember much though but you need to make the GridView fresh again as if it was loaded the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get what's your problem now.

You don't need to create a new session everytime

here is a snippets;

```
 DataTable dt;
 if (Session["Insert"]_== null) //or nothing
  {
     dt = new DataTable();
  }
  else
  {
    dt = (DataTable)Session["Insert"];

  }

  //Add to dt.Rows here
  //Save it again to Session["Insert"]
  //Then bind dt to GridView again 

This way you won't need new sessions and your dt data is retained,
```

Comment: Can you do changes in my code which i gave above, so that i can understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Creating DataTable dt
 DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Declare dt only once. If this wont work put it in a get set property.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
 {  
     if ((!IsPostBack) 
     {
        CreateDataTable();
        LoadDataTable();
     }

    gdvView = Nothing; //or Null;
    gdvView.DataSource = dt;
    gdvView.DataBind();

 }

protected void CreateDataTable()
{

//Creating DataTable Columns
    dt.Columns.Add("FName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("MName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("LName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("EId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("PCode", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("AOI", typeof(string));

 }

protected void LoadDataTable()
{
     if ((Session["Insert"] == null) //or (Session["Insert"] == nothing)
     {
         Session.Add("Insert", dt);
     }
     else {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["Insert"];
     {
}

protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//Do whatever you need to do as is
dt.Rows.Add(txtFN.Text, txtMN.Text, txtLN.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEId.Text,     ddlState.Text, ddlCity.Text, txtCountry.Text, txtPCode.Text, rdGender.SelectedValue,    cbAOI.SelectedValue);

LoadDataTable();

 /* Remove this block if you don't need it here */
    gdvView = Nothing; //or Null;
    gdvView.DataSource = dt;
    gdvView.DataBind();
 /* Remove this block if you don't need it here */

lblMandatory.Text = "Successfully Inserted into Database";
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. Here, I am testing if there already exist a value in this session, "Insert". If yes, a new row is being appended to it otherwise, a new DataTable is created.

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Creating DataTable dt

 DataTable dt;
 if (Session["Insert"] == null) //or nothing
 {
     dt = new DataTable();

     //Creating DataTable Columns
     dt.Columns.Add("FName", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("MName", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("LName", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("EId", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("PCode", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("AOI", typeof(string));
 }
 else
 {
    dt = Session["Insert"] as DataTable;
 }

    dt.Rows.Add(txtFN.Text, txtMN.Text, txtLN.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEId.Text, ddlState.Text, ddlCity.Text, txtCountry.Text, txtPCode.Text, rdGender.SelectedValue, cbAOI.SelectedValue);

    //Creating Session object to store DataTable dt
    Session["Insert"] = dt;

    lblMandatory.Text = "Successfully Inserted into Database";
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```